# Check if EditText with "inputType = number" is null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check if the input in EditText in null or not .

```
if(editTextSum.getText().toString() != null) {
  userStartingBalance = Integer.valueOf(editTextSum.getText().toString());
} else {
  userStartingBalance = 0;
}
```

Here userStartingBalance is `Integer` type .

But I am getting an error everytime that

Can't convert `" "` into `int` , and the line is pointed to the 'if case' if I don't enter anything.

Why is it not going to else case?

What should be the workaround?

Comment: One problem is that `userStartingBalance` is `int`, as you point out. And `Integer` is type `int`; yet `valueof()` takes an `int` as a parameter, but you have `toString()`. So *you are passing a `string` to a parameter which requires `int`.* Please reference https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly handling the case in which your EditText simply has no content in it.

In this case, `editTextSum.getText().toString()` will not return null (in fact, that should never be null). Instead, it will return an empty string.

Instead, you might want to try `editTextSum.getText().toString().isEmpty()` instead,. [`isEmpty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) will return true if the length is 0.

Answer (score 1):

try:

`Integer.parseInt(editTextSum.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 0):

**Why is it not going to else case ?**

Because you are calling ToString() on Null. If the field has no value present then it wil set  NULL to it and if you try to run the toString() method you will receive this error. Do the Null check before retrieving the value.

**Workaround**

```
if( editTextSum.getText() != null )
{
    userStartingBalance = Integer.parseInt(editTextSum.getText().toString());
}
else
{
    userStartingBalance =0;
}
```